# Downgrade Gnome 42.4 to 40

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, version

Hi I am using Arch linux with Gnome 42.4. I noticed some shell-extensions doesn't support gnome 42. Is there anyway to downgrade Gnome to 40. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [arch wiki covers downgrading packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/downgrading_packages). In order to return to an older version of the package you might issue the following command:

```
# pacman -U file:///var/cache/pacman/pkg/package-old_version.pkg.tar.type
```

Assuming you still have it on the cache. Else you can download it from a mirror.